# Set Controller Property Asynchronously In Constructor

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dependency-injection, async-await

I have a ***fully async*** MVC API that injects an interface into all of its controllers:

```cs
public PageController(IDataAdapter dataAdapter) {
    _dataAdapter = dataAdapter;
}
```

The implementation of the interface needs to have an access token set on its SQLConnection object. This access token is needed for the managed identity secure access (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi). This token needs to be set when the controller is constructed, so on every new request. The token can change, so we can't have it be a static value. This is what we have in the interface implementation today:

```cs
public partial class DataAdapter : BaseEntityDataAdapter, IDataAdapter {
    AppInsightsLogger _log = new AppInsightsLogger();

    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>   
    /// Instantiate the data adapter and pull out the dsn information
    /// </summary>
    public DataAdapter() : base("db") {
        try {
            var conn = base.Database.Connection as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
            conn.AccessToken = (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            _log.LogError(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that we use *.Result* to evaluate the async operation, which in turn is actually running it synchronously. I know I should be using a factory pattern, like this below instead:

```
public async Task<DataAdapter> ConstructAdapterAsync() {
    try {
        DataAdapter da = new DataAdapter();
        var conn = da.Database.Connection as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
        conn.AccessToken = await (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");

        return da;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        _log.LogError(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But this still leaves me with the problem that in the controller constructor, I can't call an async factory function without forcing it to run synchronously. Is there anyway that I can set this property asynchronously?

Comment: The simple answer is: Don't do async stuff in constructors, initialise those things elsewhere. Never use `.Result` either, especially in ASP.NET as you could end up blocking.

Comment: @DavidG sure but in this case is there anyway around this? The constructors for the API controllers automatically get called by the framework when a new request comes in (as far as I understand it), and this property needs to get set before anything on the database gets hit

Comment: Perhaps you need a factory that creates SQL connections. Your controller constructor can have the factory as a dependency. Then when you need a SQL connection (in your action methods) you can call asynchronous methods on the factory to obtain a properly constructed connection that has the access token.

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to some something similar, I used a factory pattern, but with two key things:

1. Make the factory method a static method in the class itself, since this gives you access to the `private` properties and methods.
2. Mark the constructor as `private` so that no one can use the class without using the factory method.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```cs
public partial class DataAdapter : BaseEntityDataAdapter, IDataAdapter {
    AppInsightsLogger _log = new AppInsightsLogger();

    private DataAdapter() : base("db") { }

    public static async Task<DataAdapter> ConstructAdapterAsync() {
        DataAdapter da = new DataAdapter();
        try {
            var conn = da.Database.Connection as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
            conn.AccessToken = await (new AzureServiceTokenProvider()).GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/");

            return da;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            da._log.LogError(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```